# Facebook ReactJS and Zurb Foundation for Apps?

Tags: zurb-foundation, reactjs, reactjs-flux

I like Zurb Foundation (SASS and especially Zurb Foundation for Apps) but would like to use it with Facebook ReactJS and Flux

That is removing AngularJS and replacing it with ReactJS / Flux.  A great start towards this goal has been made by Kiran Abburi:

https://github.com/akiran/react-foundation-apps

http://webrafter.com/opensource/react-foundation-apps

What do people think about the long-term viability of using Zurb Foundation for Apps with Facebook ReactJS / Flux like this?

From both technical and ecosystem perspective (e.g. updates).

Or alternatively, is a CSS framework like Zurb Foundation (or Twitter Bootstrap) really beneficial at all with ReactJS / Flux.

Thanks,
Ashley.

Comment: It's strange that you would ask this question today as the company that I work for was looking into doing the same thing. I found your question while doing research into this very question. I must ask: why do you want to move away from angular?

Comment: For all the reasons Facebook mentioned in their ReactJS intro, e.g. the two-way binding and architecture may not scale well for large apps, in terms of complexity and speed. We also are not really moving away as much as choosing ReactJS & Flux for our new project.

Comment: I am the author of react-foundation-apps. I love to maintain this project. If you have any feedback or found any bugs, feel free to open an issue or submit a pull request.

Comment: We're using Foundation/ReactJS as well, it plays well together. However I find your question very subjective, it doesn't come up with a concrete problem.

Answer (score 4):

Well whatever css framework pair up with whatever shouldn't be your long-term viability concern. Front End technologies changes too fast. IE. for the mainstream, couple years ago everything is jquery, than comes backbone, ember, angular, now react.js and than maybe riot.js. When Angular 2 releases stable version, it probably shift it again.

Your questions should be which ever framework help you do YOUR JOB quicker. Different clients might want different things, some clients i dealt with uses Bootstrap, they provide their corporate design patterns and some of their reusable jQuery * bootstrap widgets to implement, some gave me backbone models and ask me to use it in an angular as an angular service. And some asks me to do it in stylus instead of sass.

So pairing up css and js framework isn't any of my concern for long term, the trend changes too quickly. And the good thing about react is that you can bundle all these third party libraries into one single component ( if you really want do do that. Eg; embedded css into complement with react-styles, if some of your component uses jQuery, you can do a script lazy load at componentWillMount life cycle. ), you got the total freedom, if some strange case that you want to uses both foundation popup and bootstrap popup together on the same page, you can write your own react components to wrap one of each, as long as you got the scope well managed.

Which ever css framework you use as long as it saves you time to do things is beneficial, there isn't a best one, my team built our own css and js framework on top of any libraries to tailor it for our job.